# Starting and Stopping Another Process when Mongrel Rails starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lighttpd, mongrel

I would like to start another process when mongrel rails starts up.  Is there a way to do this?  I am looking to start lighttpd which acts as a media server on my project every time rails starts and stop it every time rails stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a new init script for starting lighttpd when you start the mongrel cluster. Set it to be executable and place it where your other init scripts reside (/etc/init.d/ on Debian based distributions).

- **Start:** Start the mongrel cluster and start lighttpd
- **Stop:** Stop the mongrel cluster and stop lighttpd
- **Restart:** Stop and start

Comment: You're right, rather than trying to sneak code into mongrel starting up, I need to write something that starts mongrel + lighttpd and then stops them together.  This is the right idea.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont see why you cant configure lighttp as a reverse proxy for a mongrel cluster or even use nginx with passenger

Answer (score 0):

If you use nginx/Apache (nginx is my preference) to run your app on passenger then why couldn't your chosen web server just serve your static files?